# Optimization tool in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I accidently saw that there is a feature in VS2010 (built in, I believe) which tells you how to make your c# code more good looking, i.e. "it's better to write here not like this, but like this", but I couldn't find this tool. And one more question, is there any tool, which can perform the code analysis for unhandled exceptions?

Answer (score 6):

I highly suggest: [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) plug-in.

Comment: Awesome. Mark this as the answer if this is what you went with. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're talking about [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Could be [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/), though I sometimes question it's fashion taste. StyleCop enforces consistency in code style (aka "better looking") but does nothing semantically to the code. Visual Studio's built in Code Analysis is about semantics and grew out of FxCop.